# How to prevent Client from crashing while the server is not running?

Tags: c#

I'm new to c# and trying to set up a server client connection for some test purpose.

Currently I have this snippet letting my client app crashing when it trys to connect while the server isn't running. It seems to me the crash is happening in the `client.Connect` line, letting me no chance to prevent this, as it didn't return form the method when the crash happens.

Also looking on MSDN didn't give me some usefull info.

so would I have to make some preperation?
because just checking a return value isn't possible as the crash happens inside the method.

Or is there a way I had to check before for I run the connect mehtod for connectability?

```
        Int32 port = 4999;
        Byte[] teststring;
        GameConfiguration objGameConfClient = new GameConfiguration();
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient();

        client.Connect("XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX", port);

        if (client == null)
        {
            return;
        }
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
The MSDN example apears to me also not handling this crash, is it?

Comment: Can you see the `try { ... } catch(SocketException ex){}` in the MSDN example? That should point you in the right direction.

Comment: @Rhumborl is try catch the solution for every error prevention in C#? And where I can find such Keywords as `SocketException` ofr later problems?

Comment: This won't stop the error from happening but it is essentially the only way to handle the error in your own code and stop it crashing your program completely. You can often get away with just `catch(Exception e)` (all types of Exception inherit from this), but best practice is to catch specific types. If you look at the specific method you are calling on MSDN, in your case [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s2yca91(v=vs.110).aspx), you can usually see the Exceptions that the method can throw. Then you can catch specific types or just a general `Exception` as you require. Phew.

Comment: Ah thats nice to know. thanks. Its pretty hard to learn new language and want to start with writing good practice ^^

Comment: Excellent, good to start off on the right foot :) This page isn't a bad overview of Exception handling in C# - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
try
{
    client.Connect("XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX", port);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    //XXX
}
```